# jQuery Mobile: How to make dialog open more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, dialog

I'm not sure if it is a bug or if it the standard method of a dialog box in jQuery Mobile but I have a `dialog` box that opens when you click the button and the page is newly loaded. However, when you close it and open it again, it flashes open and closes. Is there a way to have the dialog box open more than once??

**EDIT:** I have edited my code to include a second `data-role="page"` because my issue only occurs on the second page.

Here is my code:

## HTML:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>List App</title>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../JS/jquery.mobile.icons-1.4.5.min.css"></script>
    <script src="../JS/list.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/stylesheet.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/jquery.mobile.icons-1.4.5.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/jquery.mobile.inline-png-1.4.5.min.css"/>

    </head>

     <body>

<!--FIRST PAGE-->   
<div data-role="page" id="filterPage">

        <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
             <h1>List App</h1>
       </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <ul data-role="listview" id="chipperList" data-filter="true" data-filter-reveal="false" data-filter-placeholder="Chose a County..." data-divider-theme="a" data-inset="false" data-transition="slide" >
                <li data-role="list-divider" data-theme="b" role="heading" >County</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
 </div>  

<!--SECOND PAGE-->
        <div data-role="page" id="listDetails">
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
             <h1>List App</h1>
             <div data-role="navbar" data-rel="back">
              <a href="#filterPage" class="ui-btn ui-icon-search ui-btn-icon-left">Return to Search</a>
              </div>
            </div>

    <div data-role="content"></div>



        <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed">
            <div data-role ="navbar">    
                <ul>
        <li><a href="#freeCoupon" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop">Free Coupon</a></li> 


                </ul>
            </div>
            </div>


    </div> 


<!--COUPON--> 
         <div data-role="dialog" id="freeCoupon"> 
             <div data-role="header" data-theme="b"> 
             <h1>Congratulations!</h1>      
    </div>
             <div data-role ="content">
                <img src="../CSS/IMAGES/coupon.jpg"/>
             </div> 
         </div>

    </body>   

    </html>
```

## LIST.JS

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#filterPage", function () {
$.getJSON("../JSON/list_data.json", function(info){

    var li = "";
    $.each(info, function (i, name) {
        li += '<li><a href="#" id="' + i + '" data-transition="slide" class="info-go">' + name.county + '</a></li>';
        $("#chipperList").empty();


    $("#chipperList").append(li).promise().done(function () {

        $(this).on("click", ".info-go", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#listDetails").data("info", info[this.id]);


            $.mobile.changePage("#listDetails");
        });


        $(this).listview("refresh");
    });
});
});
});



$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#listDetails", function () {

    var info = $(this).data("info");

    var info_view = "";
    for (var key in info) {
        info_view += '<div class="ui-grid-a"><div class="ui-block-a"><div class="ui-bar field" style="font-weight : bold; text-align: left;">' + key + '</div></div><div class="ui-block-b"><div class="ui-bar value" style="width : 70%">' + info[key] + '</div></div></div>';
    }

    $(this).find("[data-role=content]").html(info_view);
});
```

## LIST_DATA.JSON

```
[{
        "county": "Antrim",
        "name": "Flash in The Pan",
        "address": "Main Street, Bushmills",
        "info": "Dummy Text"
    }, {
        "county": "Armagh",
        "name": "The Galley",
        "address": "Barrack Street, Armagh",
        "info": "Dummy Text"
    }, {
        "county": "Carlow",
        "name": "Roosters",
        "address": "Market Square, Bagenalstown",
        "info": "Dummy Text"
    }
]
```

Comment: Do you have any javascript with this?

Comment: No no javascript except for the files linked in the `<script>` tags. Should I have??

Comment: If it is not solved yet I can help you

Comment: Not really. I scrapped the `dialog` on the second page but I was using the `data-rel="back"` on that page which gave the same problem and had to use `data-ajax="false"` which meant I lost the page transition

Comment: @cigarette_unicorn i am not getting you

Comment: I couldn't get the `dialog` to work on the second page `#listDetails` so moved it to the first page  `#filterPage` where it works fine. On the `#listDetails` page I also had a back button that had the same problem as my `dialog` in that it only opened the previous page then instantly reverted back to the second page. To fix that I had to use  `data-ajax="false" ` which reloads the page meaning I couldn't apply a page transition.

Comment: @cigarette_unicorn check my answer

Answer (score 0):

This code will solve your problem:

**Home.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>List App</title>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../JS/jquery.mobile.icons-1.4.5.min.css"></script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/stylesheet.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/jquery.mobile.icons-1.4.5.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/jquery.mobile.inline-png-1.4.5.min.css"/>
    <script>
    $(document).on("pageinit", "#filterPage", function () {
    $.getJSON("../JSON/list_data.json", function(info){
    var li = "";
    $.each(info, function (i, name) {
        li = $('<li class="info-go"><a href="#" id="' + i + '" data-transition="slide" >' + name.county + '</a></li>');
        li.data("info",name);



    $("#chipperList").append(li);

    });
    $("#chipperList").listview("refresh");
    });
    });

     $(document).on("click", ".info-go", function (e) {

            $("#listDetails").data("info", $(this).data("info"));


            $.mobile.changePage("#listDetails");
        });



$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#listDetails", function () {

    var info = $(this).data("info");

    var info_view = "";
    for (var key in info) {
        info_view += '<div class="ui-grid-a"><div class="ui-block-a"><div class="ui-bar field" style="font-weight : bold; text-align: left;">' + key + '</div></div><div class="ui-block-b"><div class="ui-bar value" style="width : 70%">' + info[key] + '</div></div></div>';
    }

    $(this).find("[data-role=content]").html(info_view);
});
    </script>
    </head>

     <body>

<!--FIRST PAGE-->   
<div data-role="page" id="filterPage">

        <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
             <h1>List App</h1>
       </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <ul data-role="listview" id="chipperList" data-filter="true" data-filter-reveal="false" data-filter-placeholder="Chose a County..." data-divider-theme="a" data-inset="false" data-transition="slide" >
                <li data-role="list-divider" data-theme="b" role="heading" >County</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
 </div>  

<!--SECOND PAGE-->
        <div data-role="page" id="listDetails">
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
             <h1>List App</h1>
             <div data-role="navbar">
              <a href="#filterPage" class="ui-btn ui-icon-search ui-btn-icon-left" ata-rel="back">Return to Search</a>
              </div>
            </div>

    <div data-role="content"></div>



        <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed">
            <div data-role ="navbar">    
                <ul>
        <li><a href="dialog.html" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop">Free Coupon</a></li> 


                </ul>
            </div>
            </div>


    </div> 

    </body>   

    </html>
```

**dialog.html**

```
 <div data-role="dialog" id="freeCoupon"> 
             <div data-role="header" data-theme="b"> 
             <h1>Congratulations!</h1>      
    </div>
             <div data-role ="content">
                <img src="../CSS/IMAGES/coupon.jpg"/>
             </div> 
         </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to remove the "../" from this line:

```
<script src="../JS/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

to this:

```
 <script src="JS/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: For some reason my text editor doesn't automatically link the file if I type it that way.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know, check my working [example] (https://jsfiddle.net/ejk8o1kb/3) . Is your code different from this?

Comment: I think the problem is that the `dialog` is being opened on a new page. It works fine on the first page. See my updated code in the question.

Comment: Your code works if I open the dialog on the first page.

Answer (score -1):

You may need to set `autoOpen` to false and apply a click event handler to the dialog as this problem sounds like the dialog is being re-created every time it's clicked.

Try adding this to the page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#freeCoupon').dialog({
        autoOpen: false
    });

    $('#freeCoupon').click(function() {
        $('this').dialog('open');
    });
});
```

**Edit:**

If that doesn't work then I'm going to guess the jQuery Mobile files aren't being linked properly. For the time being, try using the CDN URLs and replace:

```
<script src="../JS/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css"/>
```

with:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
```

Comment: No it's still flashing open then closed. My back button using `data-rel="back"` is doing the same.

Comment: @cigarette_unicorn It might be that the files aren't linked properly. Try removing the JS in my answer and see my edit.

Comment: @cigarette_unicorn that is very strange because it's working properly on my machine. Are you using an older browser or mobile phone to view this by chance?

Comment: I'm using Chrome, my localhost and Ripple phone emulator.

Comment: I have updated my code accordingly, but I realised the code works fine on the first page but not on the second. Any suggestions?

Comment: @cigarette_unicorn The HTML looks fine to me and works on my machine. What is list.js?

Comment: I have updated the question to include the js and json files. I don't understand what the source of the problem is at all.